# What is the best way to check if a pdf document contains embedded files?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am looking for the best way to check with java if a pdf document contains embedded files.

This following solution works, but it would be a nicer to have solution that requires less memory.

```
org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument pdDocument = PDDocument.load(bytes);
PDDocumentNameDictionary names = new PDDocumentNameDictionary(pdDocument.getDocumentCatalog());
PDEmbeddedFilesNameTreeNode efTree = names.getEmbeddedFiles();
boolean result = efTree != null
```

By the way I use Apache Pdf-Box 1.8.9

Do you know a better way to check the embedded files?

Comment: use the current version and set a scratch file when opening.

Comment: thank you. `PDDocument.loadNonSeq(inputStream, scratchfile);` works better.

Comment: The current version  is 2.0.9. 1.8.9 is outdated.

Comment: thank you for your advice. we can't do a major version update.